# How to run shell script through "out_exec" plugin?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, fluentd

There a log file which delivers the message from FluentD to Kafka (FluentD --> Kafka).

Fluentd configurations Settings are as below.

```
<source>
@type tail
path /home/ubuntu/demo/files/test
pos_file /home/ubuntu/demo/fluentd/test.log.pos
tag fluentd.example
format none
</source>
<match *.**>
@type kafka_buffered
brokers localhost:9092
default_topic fluentd-example
max_send_retries 1
</match>
```

Whenever FluentD delivers the message to Kafka, we would like to know does the message got delivered to the Kafka or not(acknowlegement).

I feel, its possible through "out_exec" fluentd plugin. Correct me if I am wrong or suggest me is there any other ways.

How to run shell script through "out_exec" plugin?

Answer (score 0):

How about `required_acks` parameter?
https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-kafka

Comment: Where can I see the acknowledgement message?